# Grails modify Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

I have web application ( built using Grails ) in which I am using Spring Security with LDAP.

Login and logout behaviour works fine in application.

Now, I wanted to build the functionality where if admin is logged in application first time forward user to specific page instead of sending user to index/home page.

I modified LoginController ( auth method ) and tried to keep track of login by new domain class.  But after login Login controller "auth method" is not called.

can anyone point me to right direction ? is there other controller I need to modify ?

Answer (score 1):

The default Spring Security login form POSTs to a special URL: `/j_spring_security_check` (the exact URL used can be changed through the `apf.filterProcessesUrl` configuration parameter)  This POST request is handled by the Spring Security internals.  To add custom login logic, you can implement your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` as described [here](http://omarello.com/2011/09/grails-custom-target-urls-after-login/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to work on this as soon as I get time.